# Prove that a finite number of inequalities make a line in R^n.

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

I want show that a line ( which is defined as $$ L = \{  x_0 + \lambda d : \lambda \in \mathbb R^n \} $$ ) is a polyhedral set and for that I need to prove that we can show any line in R^n by a fine number of linear inequalities .

Answer (score 1):

Any $n-1$-hyperplane can be written as a linear equation of $n$ variables.

Any linear equation can be written as two matching inequalities with opposite sense.

Any $m-k$-hyperplane can be written as the intersection of $k+1$ $m$-hyperplanes.

Comment: Where can I find the proof ?

Comment: The dimension of a hyperplane is always one less than the dimension of the space then what’s a m-k hyperplane ?